# Loop movie and mix with audio by ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a movie file and an audio file with different length.

Audio file is longer than video file.

I want to loop video and mix with audio, then set length same as audio file.

```
ffmpeg -i "Pentagon_VJ_background_loop.mp4" -stream_loop -1 -t 60 -i "Out1.wav"  -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output.mp4
```

With this I have `-stream_loop -1` but movie doesn't loop. and have no way to set the length to audio file(I use `-t 60` instead).

Does anyone help??

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i "Pentagon_VJ_background_loop.mp4" -i "Out1.wav" -shortest -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output.mp4
```

Explanation:

- `-stream_loop -1` must be placed before the file that you want to loop
- `-shortest` tells ffmpeg that output.mp4 should have the duration of the shortest input. Since the video is now an endless video, the shortest input is the audio file.